# Finding limit in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis, distribution-theory

I tried to solve the following limit in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon}{2} \left|x \right|^{\epsilon -1}
\end{equation}

I began by thinking of testing on a $\phi \in \mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R})$, but all my approaches (part integration, thinking of a derivative anywhere) were unsuccessful...any help is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try integration by parts again cutting the integral in 2 at $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f_\epsilon(x)=\frac12 sign(x) |x|^\epsilon \to \frac12 sign(x)$$

$$f_\epsilon' \to \delta$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! But just to be sure I understood well: in the second line, formally, it means that I am deriving simply the two functions above (knowing that the distributional derivative of sign(x) is $2\delta$), or is there some passage with test functions to operate in the middle?

Comment: $f_\epsilon$ is continuous and piecewise $C^1$ thus its distributional derivative is given by its usual derivative, it converges in $L^1_{loc}$ to $sign(x)/2$ which is piecewise $C^1$ but not continuous, it has a jump discontinuity thus its distributional derivative has a $\delta$ term

Comment: Understood, thank you!